# How to replace specific integer number with a character in python using regex?

Tags: python, regex, string, replace, numbers

I tried to replace a specific number like 22 in my string with a string like "Hi there", but it also replace float numbers like 22.14 in my string (Hi there.14).

```
  import re
  my_string = "22 and 22.14"
  re.sub(r'\b22\b', "Hi there", my_string)
```

Comment: I think you are looking for `\b22\b`  You are using  a quantifier `{22}` on a word boundary `\b` which does not work.

Comment: I edited my question's code.

Comment: Now it works right? see a [demo](https://ideone.com/cq1mT0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex, which will not let it match decimal values by using positive lookahead to ensure it only matches if `22` is followed by a space or end of input.

```
\b22(?= |$)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wtEzek/1)**

If you want `22` to be matched at the end of line ending with a `.` then you can use this regex,

```
\b22(?!\.\d)
```

**[Demo where line ends with 22.](https://regex101.com/r/wtEzek/3)**

Comment: This is correct assuming sentence is not ending with a number. In that case, it will fail.

Comment: It will work even if the sentence ends with a number. See this [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wtEzek/2)

Comment: Not if it is a valid sentence with `.` being a delimiter

Comment: Ok, if that case needs to be handled too, I can simply use a negative lookahead ensuring `22` is not followed by a dot and at least a number. Let me update my answer.